# Cannot add constructors after adding a handler to httpclient

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, visual-studio-2017, dotnet-httpclient

**Why can't I add authentication details after adding a `DelegatingHandler`?**

Prior to adding the `DelegatingHandler`, I was able to instantiate the `HttpClient` like so:

```
var client = new HttpClient{Credentials = ..., BaseAddress = ...};
```

After having added a `DelegatingHandler`, I am unable to add `Credentials` and `BaseAddress`:

```
var client = new HttpClient(new RetryHandler(new HttpClientHandler()));
client.BaseAddress = // does not exist!
client.Credentials = // does not exist!
```

**How do we add credentials and a baseaddress to this client?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can pass credentials into your handler:

```
var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    Credentials = ...
};

var retryHandler = new RetryHandler(clientHandler);

var client = new HttpClient(retryHandler )
{
    BaseAddress = ...
};
```